# scanf() running only once inside for loop

Tags: c

I am a newbie to C programming. I am trying to solve a question using scanf in loop, but the problem is that scanf is only running once inside the loop. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    int x=0;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
         char stat[3];
         scanf ("%s", stat);
        if (strcmp(stat, "X++")==0)
            x++;
        else if (strcmp(stat,"++X")==0)
            x++;
        else if (strcmp (stat, "--X")==0)
            x--;
        else if (strcmp(stat, "X--")==0)
            x--;
    }
    printf ("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the scanf running only once even when n is 2, 3 or anything else?

Comment: `char stat[3];` doesn't have space for null terminator (as it appears you intend to give 3 char inputs).

Comment: Yeah as @usr states, you are probably stepping over memory and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Your code works well in my machine. `X++` `X++` `X++` gives me 3 (1 + 1 + 1 = 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be because the value of the variable `n` is destroyed by out-of-bounds write.

Your buffer `stat` don't have insufficient size to store 3-character string because there are no room to store terminating null character.

Increase buffer size and limit number of characters to read for safety.

Checking if reading is successful will make it safer.

```
         char stat[3];
         scanf ("%s", stat);
```

should be

```
         char stat[4];
         if (scanf ("%3s", stat) != 1) return 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as intended now.